# LinqToSql and HashBytes

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I need to execute this Sql command (which works fine in management studio):

```
select * from Users where Login = 'test' and PasswordHash = HashBytes('SHA1', 'test')
```

I wrote this c# linqtosql:

```
var user = db.ExecuteQuery<User>("select * from Users where Login = {0} and PasswordHash = HashBytes('SHA1', {1})", loginTextBox.Text.Trim(), passwordPasswordBox.Password).SingleOrDefault();
```

but it never works!!

can anybody help me?

thanks!

This is the DataContext's log:

```
select * from Users where Login = @p0 and PasswordHash = HashBytes('SHA1', @p1)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [test]
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [test]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: Whatever the answer is, I would convert this to a parameterized query or else you'll leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I don't think so, because ExecuteQuery converts any {x} to @p1, @p2 etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I profiled it via `db.Log = Console.Out`, with the result:

```
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

select * from Users where Login = @p0 and PasswordHash = HashBytes('SHA1', @p1)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Admiral Trask]
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Arutha]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

Looking at this, I *imagine* the problem is that the param is `NVarChar` rather than `varchar` - so taking the hash (a binary operation) is different. If you *hashed* it as `varchar`, you should probably cast the string to `varchar` before the `HASHBYTES`.

The following works, for example:

```
var user = db.ExecuteQuery<User>(@"select * from Users where Login = {0}
        and PasswordHash = HashBytes('SHA1', CAST({1} as varchar(40)))", cn, pw)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

A simpler illustration of this is:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1','12345'), HASHBYTES('SHA1',N'12345')
```

Answer (score 3):

What you really want to do is to map a C# method to the db function HashBytes, which is done something like this

```
[Function(Name = "HashBytes")]
[return: Parameter(DbType = "VarChar(100)")]
string HashBytes(string hashtype, string text)
{  .... }
```

Details are given here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386973.aspx

That will allow you to write the query in proper LINQ:

```
var q = from u in db.Users
        where u.Login == cn && u.PasswordHash == HashBytes("SHA1", pw)
        select u;
```

Comment: HashBytes doesn't return varchar, isn't restricted to 100, and as it happens this still won't work "as is" as it will still treat `text` as `nvarchar`, giving the wrong result for what the OP needs.

Comment: This works well for me:
[Function(Name = "HASHBYTES", IsComposable = true)]
public byte[] HashBytes(string algorithm, Binary input) {}

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed quotes in template string for login and password.

```
var user = db.ExecuteQuery<User>("select * from Users where Login = '{0}' and PasswordHash = HashBytes('SHA1', '{1}')", loginTextBox.Text.Trim(), passwordPasswordBox.Password).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is 'select * from Users' SQL command returns anything from C# ?

Comment: you don't need quotes here; it is parameterized

Comment: And what is result when you run "select * from Users where Login = 'test' and PasswordHash = HashBytes('SHA1', 'test')" from C#?